# Duplicate Column Name in SQL (Impala)

Tags: sql, where-clause, impala, partition

My below SQL returned error `AnalysisException: Duplicate column name: all_periods_int`:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_nielsen_other_upc_all_markets_test;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_nielsen_other_upc_all_markets_test
PARTITIONED BY (all_periods_int)
STORED AS PARQUET
AS
SELECT          
                    COALESCE(gap.all_markets,fct.all_markets) AS all_markets,
                    COALESCE(gap.all_periods, fct.all_periods) AS all_periods,
                    NVL(gap.dollar,0) - NVL(fct.dollar,0) AS dollar,
                    (CAST(SUBSTR(COALESCE(gap.all_periods,fct.all_periods),7,2) AS int)+2000)*10000+CAST(SUBSTR(COALESCE(gap.all_periods,fct.all_periods),1,2) AS int)*100+CAST(SUBSTR(COALESCE(gap.all_periods,fct.all_periods),4,2) AS int) AS all_periods_int
FROM                temp_nielsen_gap_total_all_markets_raw gap
FULL OUTER JOIN(

                    SELECT
                                        all_markets,
                                        all_periods,
                                        SUM(dollar) AS dollar
                    FROM                temp_nielsen_sku_facts_all_markets_raw
                    GROUP BY            all_markets,
                                        all_periods
                ) fct
ON(                 gap.all_markets = fct.all_markets AND
                    gap.all_periods = fct.all_periods
    )
WHERE           ABS(NVL(gap.dollar,0) - NVL(fct.dollar,0)) > 1 AND
                fct.all_markets in (SELECT DISTINCT all_markets FROM temp_nielsen_gap_total_all_markets_raw);
```

The column `all_periods_int` is created by this SQL and it doesn't exist in any of the two underlying tables.

Also, another strange thing is that both below scenarios worked fine:

1. Run the full statement without the second condition in the `WHERE` statement `fct.all_markets in (SELECT DISTINCT all_markets FROM temp_nielsen_gap_total_all_markets_raw)`;
2. Just run the `SELECT` statement without the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

I don't see anywhere `all_periods_int` would be duplicated.

Answer (score -1):

So the problem is, the partition variable can only be referred to within the PARTITION BY clause and NOT in the SELECT statement. However, as you generate the variable within the SELECT then you need to nest this step:

```
     DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_nielsen_other_upc_all_markets_test;

       CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_nielsen_other_upc_all_markets_test
       PARTITIONED BY (all_periods_int)
       STORED AS PARQUET
       AS
        SELECT
       all_markets
       , all_periods
, dollars
FROM
(
SELECT          
                    COALESCE(gap.all_markets,fct.all_markets) AS all_markets,
                    COALESCE(gap.all_periods, fct.all_periods) AS all_periods,
                    NVL(gap.dollar,0) - NVL(fct.dollar,0) AS dollar,
                    (CAST(SUBSTR(COALESCE(gap.all_periods,fct.all_periods),7,2) AS int)+2000)*10000+CAST(SUBSTR(COALESCE(gap.all_periods,fct.all_periods),1,2) AS int)*100+CAST(SUBSTR(COALESCE(gap.all_periods,fct.all_periods),4,2) AS int) AS all_periods_int
FROM                temp_nielsen_gap_total_all_markets_raw gap
FULL OUTER JOIN(

                    SELECT
                                        all_markets,
                                        all_periods,
                                        SUM(dollar) AS dollar
                    FROM                temp_nielsen_sku_facts_all_markets_raw
                    GROUP BY            all_markets,
                                        all_periods
                ) fct
ON(                 gap.all_markets = fct.all_markets AND
                    gap.all_periods = fct.all_periods
    )
WHERE           ABS(NVL(gap.dollar,0) - NVL(fct.dollar,0)) > 1 AND
                fct.all_markets in (SELECT DISTINCT all_markets FROM temp_nielsen_gap_total_all_markets_raw)) t_final;
```

Comment: Sorry for taking so long. But your answer doesn't explain scenario 1 I listed in the op. Can you advise the reason?

Comment: Your answer doesn't work either. It returned an error `AnalysisException: Partition column name mismatch: all_periods_int != dollar`

Comment: So in your original code, your drop table statement and create table statement don't have the same table name... so you are not dropping and creating a new table. That's the reason why "my answer doesn't work". Please drop the table manually first and then run the create table code WITHOUT the     IF NOT EXITS clause.

Comment: Sorry I did a typo in the op. However, I tried your method (no table name issue) and it didn't work with the error I mentioned above.

Comment: I haven't tried the code above, but Rupert's answer is essentially correct.

Comment: The general solution here is to use the syntax
`select * from (select <standard columns>, <partition columns> from ...)  alias`
You can use explicit column names instead of the * if you prefer, in which case omit the partition column names. The alias can be anything you like, but it is required.

See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IMPALA-1687 regarding why this is required.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying further Toby. Good to see more people reading into the issues on apache!

Comment: It looks like this workaround got broken in Impala 2.10 which might explain why it wasn't working for @lovechillcool. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IMPALA-6307 - which is now fixed in 2.12! So behaviour may vary depending on version. I don't have access to 2.12 to test if the workaround is still required (or works), but I tried in 2.10 and it's failing.